# how to add a class to parent child of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-class">
    <div>
      <div class="child-class">
        <div>
          <div class="child-class">
            <div>
            </div>
```

I need to add a class to second `child-class` using `jQuery`

Comment: um so select it with `.eq(1) ` ??

Comment: There are two parts: (1) locate the second child element within the `parent` `div`, then (2) add a class to the found element. What part of that do you not know how to do? You can easily find information for each of these operations doing a few seconds of Google searching if you're not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Adress the second child of the parent via CSS Selector:

```
$('.parent > .child-class:nth-of-type(2)').addClass('your-class');
```

Advantage over using `nth-of-type` instead of `nth-child` is beeing more precise in selecting what you want. The `nth-child` will select any child of your parent. `nth-of-type` will only select children with a certain type (in this case class `child-class`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:nth-child` selector at this context,

```
var elem = $(".parent > .child-class:nth-child(2)");
```

Note that, the index that is being passed into the selector would start from 1 not from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('.parent > .child-class:eq(1)').addClass('newClass');
```

```css
.child-class {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.newClass {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child-class"></div>
 <div class="child-class"></div>
 <div class="child-class"></div>
</div>
```

I've used `jQuery eq` selector.

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Hope this will help you.